# Operations inside Rails I18n locales' strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I am trying to put operations inside the locales to adapt to different languages. For example, in English a billion is 1,000,000,000,  however in Spanish a billion is 1,000,000,000,000 so I would like to be able to have the following:

```
en:
  billion: "You have %{money} billions"
es:
  billion: "Tienes %{money/1000.0} billones"
```

In order to be able to write:

```
I18n.t :billion, :money => whatever
```

And be right for whatever language.

However, it seems that I cannot put operations inside the locales' strings.

Any hint on how should I be doing this? Maybe my approach is just wrong "philosophically" talking?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on investigation, here's the solution. Sorry for the multiple edits.

```
I18n.interpolate("%{money} billion", :money => Proc.new{|x| x[:vals] / 1000}, :vals => 12121)
```

So you could change your translation file to use :vals in :en and :money in :es.

```
en:
  billion: "You have %{money} billions"
es:
  billion: "Tienes %{money_proc} billones"

I18n.t :billion, {:money => 12121, :money_proc => Proc.new{|x| x[:money]/1000.0}}
```

Comment: I noticed that the I18n gem itself was lacking some tests for code that existed. I've sent a pull request to Sven Fuchs with added tests thanks to your question.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya. This seems to be a logic solution and it works (however you have to cast the x[:money] as an Integer, otherwise it does a repeated string). On the other hand, this seems to be a bit ugly for such a simple solution we would have if Ruby interpolations are allowed. I understand this Ruby interpolations might make the YAML file a bit of a mess (as tokland pointed out) but that would happen only if you misuse them as with anything else in rails..

Comment: I agree its not aesthetic but this is the limit of interpolation you have with i18n gem. Perhaps you might fork and extend the gem itself to be able to do more. It's basically regexp substitution of tags in string with values from a hash passed during translate. Sorry, Cristobal.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just change 'billiones' to 'mil millones' in the translation?

Comment: oh, sure I could do that but the same problem might arise with other words or other languages. I don't think that quick fix is good enough in the long run ;)

Comment: Yes, but the core of a problem is the single word from the translation data. That data may be replaced by other translation of the same meaning; here it will be something that means "a count of elements that is multiplied by 10 to the power of 9". If there would be some extra construct like `billion: "You have %{money} %{numeral}"` then changes in the code would be necessary, but in case of a static word it's common to replace it by the proper word for another language. The way I see it is that someone called it "billion" which may be ambiguous, so maybe the key name is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I18n (with good judgements) allows no Ruby interpolations, the YAML files would be a mess. The Rails helper [number_to_human](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human) seems to support what you want.

[edit] Units are fixed in a frozen hash (ActionView::Helpers::DECIMAL_UNITS), so number_to_human won't be useful unless you do some tweaking before.

Comment: thanks for your reply. As far as I can tell, I18n does allow interpolations: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: @cristobal, sorry! I obviously meant Ruby interpolations.

Comment: It turns out that units are fixed in this frozen hash: ActionView::Helpers::DECIMAL_UNITS. So withouth some tweaking number_to_human won't be useful :-(